# Mojolicious: ResultSet from existing Database

Tags: sql, database, perl, odbc, mojolicious

I am currently learning Mojolicious. It makes sense and is pretty straight forward, but I can't figure out how to get a ResultSet for an existing database. After vigorous searching I came across a pretty nice walk through [here](http://oliverguenther.de/2014/04/applications-with-mojolicious-part-four-database-schemas-with-dbixclass/). However everything I read uses SQLite. If it doesn't use SQLite then it looks like you sare not able to use CRUD commands (which I think defeats the purpose of MVC model to a degree).
Can someone point me in the right direction? Currently I have something like ..

```
use lib 'C:\Users\gflynn\Desktop\WorkingCopies\MojoliciousAPP\Mojolicious

\moblo\lib\Moblo';
use Moblo::Schema;

my $schema = Moblo::Schema->connect('dbi:ODBC:driver={SQL Server};Server="server";database="db";uid="username";pwd="password"') or "Could not Connect!";
$schema->deploy();
```

.

```
    package Moblo::Schema::Result::Complaints;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table('Form_Complaints');

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  id => {
    data_type => 'integer',
    is_auto_increment => 1,
  },

  FirstName => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  LastName => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  Address => {
    data_type => ' datetime',
  },

  City => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  ZipCode => {
    data_type => 'integer',
  },

  Phone => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  AltPhone => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  Email => {
    data_type => 'text',
  },

  Complaint => {
    data_type => 'text'
  }

);
# Tell DBIC that 'id' is the primary key
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key('id');
```

Comment: Do you have `Schema.pm` in `...\moblo\lib\Moblo\Moblo`? Otherwise your `use` won't find it.

Comment: What database engine would you prefer?

Comment: @Borodin Yes I do have a Schema.pm but it is in `\moblo\lib\Moblo` and I would rather a regular SQL ODBC connection.

Comment: Then you need `use lib 'C:\Users\gflynn\Desktop\WorkingCopies\MojoliciousAPP\Mojolicious\moblo\lib'` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to modify

```
Moblo::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:moblo.db')
```

to an appropriate DSN (and username and password) for the database engine that you want to use

Take a look at [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) for more help with the DSN

Also note that [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) allows you to automatically create a schema from an existing database. It is probably better to do that than to guess what the correct settings are

Comment: I guess I was a little un-clear in my question. Do I still need to define my table (as above) if I have an existing Database? Thank you for the information.

Comment: Thank you for the information! This will get me going again.